# Error when executing `jupyter notebook` (No such file or directory)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

When I execute `jupyter notebook` in my virtual environment in Arch Linux, the following error occurred.

`Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

My Python version is 3.6, and my Jupyter version is 4.3.0

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: @LouiseDavies `pip install "ipython[notebook]"` and  `pip install jupyter`

Comment: @LouiseDavies An error occurred `-bash:：command not found`

Answer (score 194, accepted):

It seems to me as though the installation has messed up somehow. Try running:

```
# For Python 2
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter
# For Python 3
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter
```

This should reinstall everything from PyPi. This ***should*** solve the problem as I think running `pip install "ipython[notebook]"` messed things up.

Comment: This does not fix my issue. I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 and Python 3.6

Comment: pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter worked for me. Im using windows 10 and python 3.5

Comment: It helps not try to open jupyter lab in the same terminal after running all this.

Comment: It worked for me after adding --user. Without that option I was getting permission denied on a package. I remember installing that package some time ago, maybe I used sudo or something wrong like that.

Comment: It worked for me but first have to execute "pip3 install --upgrade pip"

Comment: Ran this and it messed up things so hard I had to reinstall Anaconda.

Comment: Anaconda has it's own `jupyter` package that it manages, so I'm not surprised that force installing it using `pip` messes things up. You should have instead used Anaconda's own install method `conda install`.

Comment: after reinstalling as shown, the `python -m notebook` worked for me, whereas `jupyter notebook` and `jupyter-notebook` did not.

Answer (score 75):

For me the issue was that the command `jupyter notebook` changed to `jupyter-notebook` after installation.

If that doesn't work, try `python -m notebook`, and if it opens, close it, then
`export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/`, then refresh your path by opening a new terminal, and try `jupyter notebook` again.

And finally, if that doesn't work, take a look at `vim /usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook`, `vim /usr/local/bin/jupyter`, `vim /usr/local/bin/jupyter-lab` (if you have JupyterLab) and edit the #!python version at the top of the file to match the version of python you are trying to use. As an example, I installed Python 3.8.2 on my mac, but those files still had the path to the 3.6 version, so I edited it to `#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3`

Comment: This solved my problem aswell, I'll add my anti virus( avast then) was blocking jupyter the first time - had to input the command twice.

Comment: Exactly this! Tried to uninstall and install so many stuff due to what people have been telling, but this worked like a charm.

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and Python3.

Answer (score 31):

Try this command: `python -m IPython notebook`

Credits to the GitHub user [Milannju](https://github.com/Milannju) who provided the solution [here](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_core/issues/84#issuecomment-328794208).

Comment: if you want to link to a specific spot on a website, just inspect the html, find an element you want to link to with an id and append `#ID` to the url

Comment: Yes but then you would use IPython, which always has python3 as kernel. If you want to use other kernels or other jupyter extensions, you should make jupyter work.

Answer (score 24):

[This](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2017/06/setting-up-jupyter-with-python-3-on-ubuntu/) worked for me. (Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/
```

Comment: This solved my problem; I was trying to install Toree after a standard Jupyter Anaconda installation.

Comment: Worked for me, too, I copy-pasted this command into my .bashrc to always make it work, not just in a terminal where I executed that command.

Comment: @thayakorn-rakwetpakorn the link at the start of your post is broken. I believe that [this](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2017/06/setting-up-jupyter-with-python-3-on-ubuntu/) is the correct new URL.

Answer (score 19):

On Ubuntu 18.10, the following command helped me out.

```
sudo apt-get install jupyter-notebook
```

Comment: Can you brief on it

Comment: @Billa I tried all the commands suggested by the people in this post, but I was getting the same error again and again, so I simply tried to install jupyter-notebook using apt-get and not with pip/pip3. After that I was able to open jupyter-notebook in the browser.

Answer (score 6):

Jupyter installation is not working on Mac Os

To run the jupyter notebook:-> python -m notebook

Answer (score 5):

Use the command below and if you are using pip3 replace pip by pip3

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall jupyter
```

This worked for me.

Comment: did not work for me :( . I have Ubuntu 17, jupyter does not seem to be working at all for me be it python 2.7 or python3...i have tried everything mentioned in this post..I keep getting `Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: I'm not sure if this works or not, just give a try, type    `whereis jupyter`   in terminal, delete those files and reinstall jupyter.

Comment: hey rahul..thanks this was taken care of ..long time back...thanks...all good.. :)

Comment: $ jupyter notebook Demo.ipynb 
bash: /usr/bin/jupyter: No such file or directory

Comment: /home/mona/venv/djrn/bin/jupyter

Answer (score 5):

Since both pip and pip3.6 was installed and 
`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall jupyter`
was failing, so I used

`pip3.6 install --upgrade --force-reinstall jupyter`

and it worked for me.
Running `jupyter notebook` also worked after this installation.

Answer (score 2):

**Deactivate your virtual environment if you are currently in;**

Run following commands:

**python -m pip install jupyter**

**jupyter notebook**

Comment: I like this answer because my problem was environment-specific; when I used `base` environment I saw the issue; but if I `source activate <different_environment>` I did not see the issue (`<different_environment>` was diff). Maybe the other answers (like `pip install`) should start by activating the appropriate environment.

Answer (score 1):

For me the fix was simply running `pip install notebook`

Somehow the original Jupiter install got borked along the way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to get this going on VirtualBox on Ubuntu.  Finally on some other post it said to try jupyter-notebook.  I tried this and it told me to do sudo apt-get jupyter-notebook and that installed a bunch of stuff.  Now if I type command jupyter-notebook, it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Fedora installing `python3-notebook` resolved my problem.

```
# dnf install python3-notebook
```