# Error when typing jupyter notebook (python)

Tags: python, jupyter

I get the exact same error as [Error when executing `jupyter notebook` (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648610/error-when-executing-jupyter-notebook-no-such-file-or-directory) but the solution isn't working for me.  Traditionally I have used a PC and anaconda as a package manager.  I now have a Mac using homebrew and pip which is supposedly easier but am struggling to get set up with ipython notebook.  The command I use to install jupyter is:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter --user
```

Once again the error I get is

```
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use Anaconda on a mac? I have found that to be the easiest environment to work in.

Comment: No particular reason, my mac cs friends told me this was the way to go so I'm trying it...  if I can't get it working soon Imma of course go over to Anaconda

Comment: to check that jupyter is installed and also to see if it's a problem with paths, can you tell me the response to - >>> which jupyter

Comment: and also >>>which python and >>>which python3

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/jupyter`

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/python` and I don't have python3 on the machine

Comment: have you tried running >>>/usr/local/bin/jupyter notebook

Comment: also it needs to be at least Python 2.7 not Python 2.6 >>>python --version

Comment: I have Python 2.7.13 and running `usr/local/bin/jupyter notebook` gives me `Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: can you try >>>ipython notebook

Comment: There should also be a jupyter-notebook executable in the same place as jupyter executable. Can you check with >>>which jupyter-notebook

Comment: `ipython notebook`  --> `-bash: ipython: command not found`  and `which jupyter-notebook` shows nothing

Comment: what does >>>echo $PATH say?

Comment: `/Users/cpl/miniconda2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`