# Jupyter Notebook error

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, jupyter

I am not able to run the notebook in my browser. It does not appear. The console is giving me the following error. I have Anaconda installed. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
 C:\Users\Myamoto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py:30: UserWarning: Cython.Distutils.old_build_ext does not properly handle dependencies and is deprecated.
  "Cython.Distutils.old_build_ext does not properly handle dependencies "
_cffi_ext.c
AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi\__pycache__\_cffi_ext.c(209): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/un.h': No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Myamoto\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 3, in <module>
    import notebook.notebookapp
  File "C:\Users\Myamoto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 32, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\Users\Myamoto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\Myamoto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Myamoto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Myamoto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\Myamoto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 26, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\Myamoto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants'
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648610/error-when-executing-jupyter-notebook-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 34):

I uninstalled pyzmq and re-installed it:

```
pip uninstall pyzmq 
pip install pyzmq
```

This worked for me.

Note that you may also need to reinstall the Jupyter notebook to be compatible with the latest version of Python.

Comment: Anaconda 2018.3 seems very broken under Windows 10.

Comment: This worked for me - the linked question (proposed duplicate) did not.