# Packages don't match when conda uninstall and install

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, package-management

There has been an `ImportError` when opening `jupyter notebook` so I followed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357025/jupyter-notebook-error) and ran `conda uninstall pyzmq` -> `conda install pyzmq`.

I used `conda` instead of `pip` since people say *"Don't mix up `conda` and `pip` commands under conda environment"*.

**Then I came to realise that packages for `conda uninstall pyzmq` and `conda install pyzmq` are different:**

- `conda uninstall pyzmq` ; **19** packages REMOVED
- `conda install pyzmq` ; only **3** packages INSTALLED

**Why do packages installed and uninstalled via same conda command differ?**
**Shouldn't they install and reinstall exactly corresponding packages?**

**I am still pretty new to `Anaconda`, if you have any tricks for a better `conda` envs management to minimize the risk of broken envs, your advise is greatly appreciated.**

---

#### when `conda uninstall`

```
(my_env) C:\Users\koyamashinji>conda uninstall pyzmq
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##
  environment location: C:\Users\koyamashinji\anaconda3\envs\my_env
  removed specs:
    - pyzmq

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  colorama-0.4.4-py_0
  decorator-4.4.2-py_0
  ipykernel-5.3.4-py36h5ca1d4c_0
  ipython-5.8.0-py36_1
  ipython_genutils-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  jupyter_client-6.1.7-py_0
  jupyter_core-4.7.0-py36haa95532_0
  libsodium-1.0.18-h62dcd97_0
  pickleshare-0.7.5-pyhd3eb1b0_1003
  prompt_toolkit-1.0.15-py_1
  pygments-2.7.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  python-dateutil-2.8.1-py_0
  pywin32-227-py36he774522_1
  pyzmq-20.0.0-py36hd77b12b_1
  simplegeneric-0.8.1-py36_2
  tornado-6.1-py36h2bbff1b_0
  traitlets-4.3.3-py36_0
  wcwidth-0.2.5-py_0
  zeromq-4.3.3-ha925a31_3
```

#### when `conda install`

```
(my_env) C:\Users\koyamashinji>conda install pyzmq
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\koyamashinji\anaconda3\envs\my_env

  added / updated specs:
    - pyzmq


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  libsodium          pkgs/main/win-64::libsodium-1.0.18-h62dcd97_0
  pyzmq              pkgs/main/win-64::pyzmq-20.0.0-py36hd77b12b_1
  zeromq             pkgs/main/win-64::zeromq-4.3.3-ha925a31_3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Why do packages installed and uninstalled via same conda command differ?**
> **Shouldn't they install and reinstall exactly corresponding packages?**

`conda install` and `conda uninstall` should install and uninstall exactly corresponding packages, **as long as the environment is not already broken**.
My environment was already broken probably because I used `pip` to install a few `jupyter`-related packages before (as you can see some packages are `py_0` which means they were installed via `pip install`.)

---

> **I am still pretty new to Anaconda, if you have any tricks for a better conda envs management to minimize the risk of broken envs, your advise is greatly appreciated.**

I spent my whole week trying to figure out how they work, and here's what I got (for now).

- **Make sure you specify python version supported by Anaconda at environment creation.**
  Check [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#:%7E:text=Anaconda%20supports%20Python%202.7%2C%203.6,%2C%22%20the%20default%20is%202.7.) and specify python version when `conda create -n my_env python==version`.
- **Make sure you also install all known required packages at environment creation**.
  `conda create -n my_env python=version package_A, package_B ...`
  As [Official document](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) says "*Install all the programs that you want in this environment at the same time. Installing 1 program at a time can lead to dependency conflicts.*"
- **Make sure you understand exactly what `conda install/uninstall` and `pip install/uninstall` do.**

#### `conda install/uninstall`

```
(my_env) C:\Users> conda install package_A  

# Installs : package_A + dependencies(dependency_1, dependency_2, dependency_3)
  

(my_env) C:\Users> conda uninstall package_A

# Uninstalls : package_A + dependencies(dependency_1, dependency_2, dependency_3)
```

```
(my_env) C:\Users> conda install package_A

# Installs : package_A + dependencies(dependency_1, dependency_2, dependency_3)    
  

(my_env) C:\Users> conda uninstall dependency_1

# Uninstalls : package_A + dependencies(dependency_1, dependency_2, dependency_3)
```

#### `pip install/uninstall`

```
(my_env) C:\Users> pip install package_A  

# Installs : package_A + dependencies(dependency_1, dependency_2, dependency_3)
  

(my_env) C:\Users> pip uninstall package_A

# Uninstalls : package_A ONLY
```

```
(my_env) C:\Users> pip install package_A

# Installs : package_A + dependencies(dependency_1, dependency_2, dependency_3)    
  

(my_env) C:\Users> pip uninstall dependency_1

# Uninstalls : dependency_1 ONLY
```