# Cannot use `jupyter` from `python3.x`: jupyter: command not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using a MacOS, and I'm just following the installation instructions listed here: 
http://jupyter.org/install.html

This command is satisfied:

```
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

And `jupyter` is installed:

```
$ python3 -m pip install jupyter 
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

However, none of the `jupyter` commands appear to work:

```
$ jupyter 
-bash: jupyter: command not found
$ jupyter notebook
-bash: jupyter: command not found
```

Given the paths above, is there a way to run `jupyter notebook`? It must be installed.

Comment: You could always run `python3 -m jupyter` or `python3 -m jupyter notebook`.

Comment: @Evert For the latter command, I get `Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. Does `python3 -m jupyter --help` work? See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648610/error-when-executing-jupyter-notebook-no-such-file-or-directory) with the same error, which may indicate your installation is incorrect (which may also explain why `jupyter` has not been installed or symlinked into `/opt/local/bin`).

Comment: @Evert We might be making progress. I tried this command from the link you pasted above: `python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter`. The command`python3 -m jupyter --help` does now work, but `python3 -m jupyter notebook` still gives the same error above, i.e. `Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: 1) is that the full error, or is there more traceback? 2) does the help option indicate `notebook` is a valid (sub)command? Have you tried the `console` subcommand as well, just to see whether that causes the same error?

Comment: An aside question: what Python 3 installation are you using? Since `/opt/local` is not a standard directory. That may help in finding the right solution.

Comment: @Evert (1) That's the full error I see. (2) `--help` doesn't show 'notebook' as an option. Trying 'console' throws the same error unfortunately.  I'm using '/opt/local/bin/python3', 'Python 3.4.6'. I believe this was installed with MacPorts.

Answer (score 1):

The location of the scripts is probably not in your `$PATH`.

<strike>I would *guess* they could be in `/opt/local/bin`, or maybe `/opt/bin`.</strike>

If you have the `locate` program available, try `locate bin/jupyter`. Otherwise try `find`:

```
find /opt -type f -name jupyter
```

Then add the real location of the binaries to your `$PATH`.

**edit**: [Apparently](https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/) in macos, you have to add the path you found as a new line in `/etc/paths`.

In this case, `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/‌​bin`

You should log out and then log in again for the changes in `$PATH` to take effect.

After that, start the notebook as `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It looks like `jupyter` is found here: `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/jupyter`. What do you mean by add the binaries to my `$PATH`?

Comment: Probably `export PATH="/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/‌​bin/jupyter:$PATH"`?

Comment: I'm still a bit unclear. `sudo nano /etc/paths` shows several paths: `/usr/bin` , `/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/sbin`, and `/usr/local/bin`. I've tried adding `/opt/local/` and `/opt/local/bin` to the bottom of this list, but this has not resulted in `jupyter notebook` working

Comment: @EB2127 You have to add the real path you found, `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/‌​bin`

Comment: @EB2127 You might have to log out and log in again for the change in the `$PATH` to have effect. Check that the path contains your addition with `echo $PATH`.

Comment: I think we're making progress! Now I get this error `socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known`. However, at least the command is returning something!