# Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory, how to solve it?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am installing jupyter notebook in my Ubuntu 18.04/Python 3.6 machine using [such way](https://jupyter.org/install), however, when I tried to use `jupyter notebook` to excute notebook,following error occured:

```
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

if I use `jupyter -h`,following info will be printed:

```
usage: jupyter [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir]
               [--paths] [--json]
               [subcommand]

Jupyter: Interactive Computing

positional arguments:
  subcommand     the subcommand to launch

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --version      show the jupyter command's version and exit
  --config-dir   show Jupyter config dir
  --data-dir     show Jupyter data dir
  --runtime-dir  show Jupyter runtime dir
  --paths        show all Jupyter paths. Add --json for machine-readable
                 format.
  --json         output paths as machine-readable json

Available subcommands: migrate troubleshoot
```

I have google a lot but can't find the solution.And I have tried all of the answers below [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648610/error-when-executing-jupyter-notebook-no-such-file-or-directory), none of them can solve my question.Is there anyone can help me?Thanks a lot.