# "connecting to kernel" on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook

```
[I 05:35:52.914 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 21, in <module>
    from IPython.core.application import (
  File "/Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 112, in <module>
    from IPython.core import debugger
  File "/Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py", line 48, in <module>
    from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb
  File "/Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/pdb.py", line 77, in <module>
    import code
  File "/Users/mac/Downloads/code.py", line 39, in <module>
    for elem in os.listdir('input'):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input'
[W 05:36:50.183 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from d48e4a58-d33c-4a5d-9744-20aa41c88e85
[W 05:36:54.730 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 10 on kernel d48e4a58-d33c-4a5d-9744-20aa41c88e85
```

this is the terminal window for my Jupyter notebook it does not connect to terminal I have tried

1. Uninstalling Jupyter notebook and  re-installing it.
2. Updating / downgrading the version for jupyter notebook

I am currently using macOS Big Sur 11.4, Jupyter Notebook version 6.3.0, Anaconda Navigator 2.0.3

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648610/error-when-executing-jupyter-notebook-no-such-file-or-directory/47619339) thread help you.

Comment: I would also recommend you to only use either pip or conda, and not both at the same time in their respective environments.

Comment: try to remove this line or manage code accordingly
 >>for elem in os.listdir('input'):
in 
 File "/Users/mac/Downloads/code.py", line 39